# Forgot encfs password

Tags: ubuntu, dropbox, encfs

I followed the guide here:
http://www.webupd8.org/2011/06/encrypt-your-private-dropbox-data-with.html

to get dropbox encfs working on my first computer.  I disabled the syncing of the encryption key.  so I copied it manually from the 1st computer to the 2nd computer.

By the time I had time to get this setup on the 2nd computer, I had forgotten the password I entered for encfs.

How do I remove the password from the keyring on the 1st computer before I create another key and store it in the keyring on the 1st computer?

Comment: What distro are you using and which Desktop (KDE, GNOME, etc.)?

Comment: The 1st computer is running debian wheezy gnome classic (fallback).  The 2nd computer is running ubuntu 12.04 unity3d.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not positive about GNOME 3.x but in GNOME 2.x you can get to the "Passwords and Encryption Keys app" (Applications -> Accessories -> Passwords and Encryption Keys).

From here you can manage passwords, keys, etc.

#### Screenshot

[image: ss of passwords & encryption keys app]

#### References

- [GNOME Keyring](https://live.gnome.org/GnomeKeyring)
- [Gnome Keyring tutorial and security article; Vala resources; etc](http://mdeslaur.blogspot.com/2009/11/gnome-keyring.html)
- [GNOME Keyring - wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNOME_Keyring)